# How to move csv file from one folder into another folder using SAS?

Tags: csv, sas, export-to-csv

How can I move a .csv file from one folder to another folder using SAS?
Eg. I have a file named Jan2023.csv which is present in /workspace/test/uat/user/a1/data. I need to move them to another folder named /workspace/test/uat/data using SAS.

Comment: Additionally, FCOPY to copy files (not move though). https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n10dz22b5ixohin1vwzilweetek0.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use the [RENAME() function](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/lefunctionsref/3.2/p14axci3mo3egan1okbcydvbt433.htm#p0nyx7dxpr45cun1cyy1rjhtfdrz).

```
data _null_;
  rc = rename('/workspace/test/uat/user/a1/data/Jan2023.csv'
             ,'/workspace/test/uat/data/Jan2023.csv'
             ,'file')
  ;
  put rc=;
run;
```